# Geojson mapevent second mouse click

Tags: leaflet, geojson, events

I am trying to add a geojson layer with interactive functionality to my leaflet map. I am mostly using this (dated)blog: http://palewi.re/posts/2012/03/26/leaflet-recipe-hover-events-features-and-polygons/

My result to date:

http://185.19.29.113:8080/cresh_map/mapgeojson.html

- it changes the style of a selected feature on mouseclick
- a popup come up on mouseclick
- it changes the style back on mouseover

Could anybody help me with this question:

How can I change back the style on the next mouseclick instead of mouseover?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use global variables to keep track of the current layer and popup; then reset these when you click to move to a new layer highlight:

```
// declare these in global scope, e.g. after setting highlightStyle
// name these whatever you want, case doesn't matter
var CURRENTLAYER, CURRENTPOPUP; 

layer.on("click", function (e) {
  // start by clearing the existing highlighted layer and popup, if they exist
  if (CURRENTLAYER) CURRENTLAYER.setStyle(defaultStyle); 
  if (CURRENTPOPUP) CURRENTPOPUP.remove();

  // keep a reference to the current layer that you are about to highlight
  CURRENTLAYER = layer; 

  // the remainder of your code can stay as it is...
  // but, *after* constructing the popup, keep a reference to that, too
  CURRENTPOPUP = popup;
};
```